# Is a backend database required to create a small web app dictionary of 500 words and images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I would like to create a searchable web app dictionary of about 500 words, which presents an image associated with each definition.

Is it better to store the small amount of dictionary data in a backend database, or on the user's local device?

Comment: How big is the image?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the front end you use, this will likely vary. However, almost all modern tools should easily be able to support displaying 500 words with an image/definition. If needed, you can implement a system to render the components incrementally.

I hope this helps.